# Physical Significance of the constraint

Tags: statistical-mechanics

While I was reading Mehran Kardar's book 'Statistical Physics of Particles'. The author considers three systems :
a) A wire of length L with tension F
, b) A paramagnet of magnetisation M with applied magnetic field B
, c) A gas of volume V at pressure P

Now when the system are in equilibrium the following constraints are to be satisfied:
(P + $\frac{a}{V^{2}}$)($V-b$)($L$-$L_{0}$) -$c[F-K(L-L_{0})]$ = 0 (**Equation of concern**) and (P + $\frac{a}{V^{2}}$)$(V-b)$M -$dB$ =0 and on rearranging one can get empirical temperature function '$\theta$' is proportional to (P + $\frac{a}{V^{2}}$)($V-b$) = c($\frac{F}{L-L_{0}}-K)$ = d$\frac{B}{M}$. When we say that system is in equilibrium the constraint that is satisfied has units of Work times length, so what is the physical significance of the constraint imposed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

It's just temperature $RT$. The extra factor $R$ (ideal gas constant) is to match the dimensions. This is an illustration of the 0th principle and allows you to define unambiguously temperature as the common quantity for equilibrium.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do get it in the equation (P+a/V^{2})(V-b) it's nothing but R*T, but check out the equation termed in bold 'Equation of concern', I don't get why we multiplied (P+a/V^{2})(V-b) by (L-L0) effectively the dimension is Force time (Length) squared and then we are subtracting it from a Force times c, so to match dimensions c has to be (Length) squared. So, I want to know the Physical Significance of  the equation labelled as 'equation of concern'